# Storing data to database in PySpark (Azure - DataBricks) is very slow

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am working on big dataset which is has around 6000 million records, I have performed all calculation/operation successfully. At end while I am going to store data to databricks(DBFS) Database using below command, It is taking longer time(more than 25-30 hrs), even it is not completing also. Can someone give me some good approach to handle such huge data.

```
df_matches_ml_target.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("Demand_Supply_Match_ML")
```

Let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have performed all calculation/operation successfully"? I'm asking because dataframes are lazy, they don't actually compute anything until you do an action, for example write to a table. Most likely your operations are what's taking most of the time.

Comment: This mean, code/program level everything has been done. Once I performed count() and other operations related to data. I start getting these error.

Comment: `count` and `saveAsTable` are both actions that execute the the query plan that you're building in your code. Spark has a build-plan, execute-plan model similar to the compile-code, run-code model of some programming languages. All the parts of your code up to your action (eg count or save) are building the plan, the plan doesn't actually run until you hit the action. It seems your plan builds fine but is having trouble running (is slow, is throwing errors?). There are lots of reasons your plan could have issues running, we'd need to see the code to help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like up until this point, as Bi Rico pointed out above, you've been executing "lazy" operations on your data set. Here's a [detailed summary](https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-lazy-evaluation/) of what *lazy execution* means.

Essentially, any transformations you do to your data set (such as map, flatMap, filter, etc.) will not execute until an *action* is called. An action does something that requires using a result and  some examples are writing to a file (saveAsTable), count(), take(), etc.

Since you have 6000 Million records of an unknown size, it sounds like your data set is rather large, and that is likely a huge factor in why its taking so long to execute actions.

When using Spark with Big Data, the general recommendation is to work on a smaller subset of your data. This allows you to check the validity of your transformations and code, and get results in a reasonable amount of time. Then you can apply your work to the entire data set.

*Edit on 21 Sep 2018: Recommendations for faster processing times*

It's hard to say without more information but here are some general tips.

- Avoid commands that cause shuffling (such as groupByKey). Shuffling redistributes all data to their respective partitions before merging them. This leads to lot of network I/O.
- Try to partition your data properly. This will maximize the parallel processing of your data
- Add more nodes to your cluster and/or increase the size (CPU/Memory) of your nodes. This is not an exact science. More nodes can help together with partitioning. Only increase size of nodes if they are constrained for resources.

Comment: Very nice explanation GuavaKhan... I have done all validation test using small dataset , But now I wanted to apply all my research to actual data which is rather larger... So in this situation, I am not sure how to handle this situation.  If any algorithmic approach you know, please suggest . your opinion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share more about what you are trying to do with this data? For example, is this going to be a nightly batch job to clean up information for business users to query in the morning?
Also can you share what the size (GBs, TBs, PBs) of the data set is?

Comment: Hello, This is not a nightly job. This dataset I have to use to apply Machine Learning(Data Science) .... So, if this can be break to different chunk and can be use to apply ML on stored Pyspark DataFrame. That will meet my expectation..

Comment: @shail I edited the post to reflect some recommendations on speeding up processing.

Answer (score 0):

Checkpoints will help. View the execution plan.

According to Documentation:

> Checkpointing can be used to truncate the logical plan of this
> DataFrame, which is especially useful in iterative algorithms where
> the plan may grow exponentially. It will be saved to files inside the
> checkpoint directory set with SparkContext.setCheckpointDir().

Hope this helps